# ffmpeg - Determine what parameters

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a video file that I'm trying to determine what parameters I can use to reproduce the encoding with ffmpeg.

Here's the ffprobe of the particular stream in question.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4': Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.51.107   
Duration: 00:05:02.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 4323 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 2400k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

The key part is that I'm noticing that the bitrate is quite low at 4324 kb/s, but this is actually an incredibly high quality video. To approach this sort of quality, I've only been able to make videos at 40000 kb/s (which is a huge increase in filesize). I also notice that it mentions yuvj420p which is an image format, but I have no idea what parameters with ffmpeg could produce that image format (if this at all would make a difference).

Would appreciate any help I can get.

Edit:

Here's the output based on the comment below:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=Main
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=123187/3701760
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=1920
height=1080
coded_width=1920
coded_height=1080
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=16:9
pix_fmt=yuvj420p
level=41
color_range=pc
color_space=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
chroma_location=center
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
is_avc=true
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=15/1
avg_frame_rate=1850880/123187
time_base=1/15360
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=246374
duration=16.039974
bit_rate=13795677
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=241
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
```

Edit 2:

Here's information from mediainfo

```
Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : Main@L4.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, RefFrames               : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=32
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 5 min 2 s
Bit rate                                 : 4 323 kb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.083
Stream size                              : 156 MiB (100%)
Color range                              : Full
Color primaries                          : BT.709
Transfer characteristics                 : BT.709
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709
```

Comment: `yuvj420p` is a *pixel* format.  You can set that with `-pix_fmt yuv420p`.

Comment: Also showthe  output of `strings input.mp4 | grep x264` or the `Encoding settings` in the output from mediainfo.

Comment: so your issue is you can't get the encoding quality you're looking for?  If so maybe a slower preset or crf value: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264